# Can I get malicious malware in my computer or any kinds of virus by registering through Google/Facebook to a specifc site?

Tags: malware, http, virus, internet, websites

Lately, there is a start up company in Israel called Initiative Q and currently it gives out coins (that are similar to bitcoin but they don't run on Blockchain technology) in order to advertise their services. (afterwards, these coins will supposedly have value)

As a result, there a lot of rumors now about whether it's malicious or not which I'm quite skeptical about it being mailcious because you register through google or facebook, it has a https certificate and the CEO is a well known business person.

My question:  Let's presume they have bad intents, is it resonable to have viruses planted on your PC/phone just via registering throgh Google/Facebook?

Comment: i. It is a pyramid scheme.  ii. they can resell your "sign-up" personal data to third- party.  iii. When your data falling into the criminal syndicate, they can use social engineering to trick you, the victim, e,g. phish as some authoritative party and "want" you to install something to "help" investigation.

Comment: ok, suppose someone did register, then what?
Is the email bound for life?

Comment: The problem is not the email, but the personal data harvested when one registered, all can be used against the person who leaks their own personal details to the site operator and whatever party it sold the data.  You will not get any virus unless you are trick to install one.  And the personal data is the best way to create a script to play the trick.

Comment: What I'm not understanding is how is it possible to harvest data if you do the secure registration through Gmail?
I'm not giving out any names, passwords etc.

Comment: Somebody has done the research
https://davidgerard.co.uk/blockchain/2018/06/24/initiative-q-a-non-crypto-private-currency-marketed-by-pyramid-scheme/

Comment: Definately very informitave, could you please add it as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential for getting malware has nothing to do with how you register. Installing their application is a much bigger factor in getting malware.

Comment: Yes, but there is no app, at least not currently, that's why it was so strange for me to hear some of these rumors.

but I think mootmoot's link has a good reason not to register which is the fact that they don't yet have any product so they might go bankrupt but their database is worth something and can be sold to 3rd party

Comment: Their FAQ talks about their app, which is where I got this from. Your question is about the possibility to get *malware* from OAUTH, and that's simply not possible. Yes, it is possible to gather some data from OAUTH, and the sign up process encourages the creation of a network map (your connections to the people you invite), but just using Google/Facebook OAUTH does not mean that you necessarily give everything away.